# observeenvent with two conditions

Tags: r, shiny

I have tried to nest some "observe events" in Shiny to create a conditional rule.

It should go like this :

- if one box is clicked display the corresponding single output when the button is clicked.
- if both boxes are clicked display both outputs when the button is clicked.

but it always displays both outputs.

Any suggestion?

```
shinyApp(
  ui = basicPage(
    checkboxInput("box1", label = "Checkbox1", value = FALSE),
    checkboxInput("box2", label = "Checkbox2", value = FALSE),
    actionButton('buttn', 'Validate'),
    verbatimTextOutput("out1"),
    verbatimTextOutput("out2")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(input$buttn, {

      observeEvent(input$box1, {
        output$out1 <-  renderText({"Foo"})});

      observeEvent(input$box2, {
        output$out2 <-  renderText({"bar"})})

    })
  }
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that it is bad practice to put `observeEvents` or `reactives` inside other `observeEvents`. See [this slide and the two after it from a presentation by Joe Cheng](https://cdn.rawgit.com/rstudio/reactivity-tutorial/master/slides.html#/exercise-0).

One possible solution is to simply show or hide elements with the `shinyjs` package. A working example is given below.

Another solution is to use `reactiveVal` to hold the text to be displayed, and update that from your observer.

Hope this helps!

---

**Solution 1**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)    

ui <- basicPage(
  checkboxInput("box1", label = "Checkbox1", value = FALSE),
  checkboxInput("box2", label = "Checkbox2", value = FALSE),
  actionButton('buttn', 'Validate'),
  shinyjs::hidden(div(id='div1', verbatimTextOutput("out1"))),
  shinyjs::hidden(div(id='div2', verbatimTextOutput("out2"))),
  useShinyjs()
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$buttn, {
    if(input$box1)
      shinyjs::show('div1')
    else
      shinyjs::hide('div1')

    if(input$box2)
      shinyjs::show('div2')
    else
      shinyjs::hide('div2')
  })

  output$out1 <-  renderText({"Foo"})
  output$out2 <-  renderText({"bar"})

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

---

**Solution 2**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- basicPage(
  checkboxInput("box1", label = "Checkbox1", value = FALSE),
  checkboxInput("box2", label = "Checkbox2", value = FALSE),
  actionButton('buttn', 'Validate'),
  verbatimTextOutput("out1"),
  verbatimTextOutput("out2")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  text1 <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  text2 <- reactiveVal(NULL)

  observeEvent(input$buttn, {
    ifelse(input$box1,text1('Foo'),text1(NULL))
    ifelse(input$box2,text2('Bar'),text2(NULL))
  })

  output$out1 <-  renderText({text1()})
  output$out2 <-  renderText({text2()})

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

---

[image]

---

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the extra event observers. Just observe the button click and use standard R conditional logic to adjust the output based on the checkboxes.

```
shinyApp(
    ui = basicPage(
        checkboxInput("box1", label = "Checkbox1", value = FALSE),
        checkboxInput("box2", label = "Checkbox2", value = FALSE),
        actionButton('buttn', 'Validate'),
        verbatimTextOutput("out1"),
        verbatimTextOutput("out2")
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
        observeEvent(input$buttn, {
            if (input$box1) {
                output$out1 <-  renderText({"Foo"})
            }
            if (!input$box1) {
                output$out1 <-  renderText({NULL})
            }
            if (input$box2) {
                output$out2 <-  renderText({"Bar"})
            }
            if (!input$box2) {
                output$out2 <-  renderText({NULL})
            }
        })
    }
)
```

Comment: Although this solution works, I would like to point out for future reference that setting `output` elements from inside an `observer` is not good practice in Shiny. See also the presentation in my answer or Joe Cheng's comment [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/baGy4jL8mYA).

Comment: I 100% agreed and think your solution#2 is the best practice. I try to frame solutions as close as possible to the scenario OP describes. It's always a balance between extra packages/new data constructs and helping people get unstuck :)

Comment: Alright, good to hear ;) I definitely see the point of framing solutions close to the code of OP, makes it easier for OP to see where his/her code went wrong.